Next.JS Redirect concatenate routes
I am doing a Next.js project with typescript and when I am in a profiel page "/en/profile" I am trrying to redirect for a "en/dashboard" the error occur that instead of redirecting to this it goes "/en/profile/en/dashboard"
This is the code i am using:
return redirect(
    `/${localActive}/dashboard/${id}`
  );


You need to do a relative redirect two levels up:
return redirect(
    `../../${localActive}/dashboard/${id}`
  );


